# CentOS7 Log User Activity from SFTP

Tags: centos, sftp

I haven't been able to figure out how to log user activity for my SFTP on my CentOS 7 server. I have configured rsyslog to send logs to my Syslog Server. I would like to do the same with user activity.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to log, the addition/removal of files?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this first: https://linux.die.net/man/8/sftp-server

From here you can choose what is available and what is the perfect option according to your demand; logging "user activities".

I guess the:

```
-f USER -l INFO
```

*Please follow the instructions below and modify it according to your needs.*

Question:

How to configure sftp to log the name, location, and size of the transferred files ?

Answer:

Configure the sshd_config file to log information to syslog.

```
#vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Locate the following line:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/sbin/sftp-server
```

Add the following parameters **"-l INFO -f AUTH"** at the end:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/sbin/sftp-server -l INFO -f AUTH
```

Save the */etc/ssh/sshd_config* file.

Configure syslog to record information from sftp-server.

```
# vi /etc/syslog.conf
```

Add the following line in syslog.conf

```
auth.info /tmp/sftp.log
```

Save the file */etc/syslog.conf*, create the log file, and refresh syslogd.

```
# touch /tmp/sftp.log
# refresh -s syslogd
```

Restart sshd daemon.

```
# stopsrc -s sshd
# startsrc -s sshd
```

NOTE: While stopping and starting sshd, users will not be able create new connections. Existing connections will not be disconnected.

Test the following from an sftp client.

```
# sftp user@<server-name>
password: <Enter Password>
<sftp>cd /
<sftp>put motd
```

In the syslog, you should see logged information similar to the following output, which includes the file name and size.

```
Oct 8 11:29:07 greybso auth|security:info sftp-server[372922]: open "/motd" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0666

Oct 8 11:29:07 greybso auth|security:info sftp-server[372922]: close "/motd" bytes read 0 written 880
```

*Source: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-sftp-log-filename-location-and-size-transfers*